# Outputting a txt file to a folder in internal memory in android

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I am in need to create a text file where the input is taken from the user.

I am trying to save the txt file in a folder(folder should be created even if it is not there)

My code is as follows,

```
 FileOutputStream fileos = null;

                if (FreeMemory() != 0) {
                    FileOutputStream fos=null;
                    try {
                        File path=new File(getFilesDir(),"sri");
                        if(!path.exists()){
                            path.mkdir();
                        }
                        File mypath=new File(path,"myfile.txt");
                        if (!mypath.exists()) {
                            fos = new FileOutputStream( mypath);
                            String text="Write Hii";
                            fos.write(text.getBytes());
                            fos.close();
                        }                           
                    }catch(Exception e){

                    }

                }
```

The "path" variable gives this path: "/data/data/com.example.gm/files/sri" 
  I navigated to this path in my device: Android-->Data-->com.example.gm-->files-->
  but the folder "sri" is not created and even the file also. Am I navigating to th ecorrect path ? I am not able to find out the file in the device. 
  I searched for the folder by installing "Astro File Manager" app too. But, couldn't find it. I am not getting any Exception when writing to the folder. The code must be correct. But where is the folder and file? Please anyone help me in solving this.

I want to save the txt file in internal memory of my device.

Whats wrong with my code? Please suggest me the solution. 
  I have gone through many trails and finally approached stackoverflow.

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Strange!! No one can solve this!!!

Comment: There's a fair chance that you have created the file, rather the issue is probably that unless you change the permissions of the directory and the file, nothing else will be able to see it, as you have created it in your app's private storage folder.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the internal storage is not accessible out side the application owning it, so any third party application like file browser or Astro File Manager will not be able to see the files. The application with root access will only be able to access the files in the internal memory. I believe you should programmatically verify if the file is created. getFilesDir() will give the internal memory location allocated to that app.

Answer (score -1):

Have you give the permission in manifiest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Yes I have set that permission.

Comment: Mistaken advice!  External Storage permission is not required for the location returned by getFilesDir().